# sql query which want to retreve upto 3conditions

Tags: sql, db2

I have a data in the source table as mentioned below:

```
Employee_Id Status  Date        Address Phone number
52345       N       28-Jan-10   ABC     9833455456
52345       N       30-Apr-10   ABC     9833455456
52345       Y       13-Dec-10   ABC     9934467879
10145       N       25-Mar-10   PQR     8766129989
32456       N       20-Jun-10   XYZ     9860799849
32456       N       03-Nov-10   XYZ     9860799849
32456       Y       07-Feb-11   XYZ     9860799849
32456       Y       22-May-11   XYZ     8977767889
32456       N       18-Sep-11   DEF     9811223300
42123       N       25-Feb-10   MNO     9920030048
42123       N       23-Sep-11   MNO     9833445566
```

The objective is to get the unique record for an Employee in the output but based on below mentioned criteria:

1. If Employee Id is unique, then pass it as it is.
2. If Employee Id is duplicate, then pass the record where status=”Y”
3. If Employee Id is duplicate even after applying status=”Y”, then pick the record having latest Date.

With these rules, I should be getting these results:

```
Employee_Id Status  Date        Address Phone number
52345       Y       13-Dec-10   ABC     9934467879
10145       N       25-Mar-10   PQR     8766129989
32456       Y       22-May-11   XYZ     8977767889
42123       N       23-Sep-11   MNO     9833445566
```

Comment: What query have you tried so far? Did you have a look at the `group by` and `having` clauses?

Comment: What database and version of it are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the row_number() function to get what you want.

```
select t.*
from (select t.employee_id,
             row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by status desc, date desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by employee_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and not (cnt > 1 and status = 'N')
```

This orders the rows, for each employee by status (with "Y"s first) and then by date (with latest first).  It then chooses the first of this group.

If you have only one row, then it will have seqnum = 1.

If you have only one "Y", then it will have seqnum = 1.

If you have multiple "Y"s, then this will choose the one with the latest date.

Comment: I thought I did.  The row_number() function assigns a sequential number to records, based on the partition and order by clauses.  It starts over for each group in the partition.  It orders the number based on the order by.  What database are you using?

Comment: I fixed the query.  You didn't specify in your original question what to do with multiple rows, when they are all Ns.  The original version kept one of them.  I fixed it to filter these out.